# Keeping Mongoid objects in memory after iterating over them with cursor

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm iterating over objects using the same cursor a few times, so I'm assuming that keeping the objects in memory would be faster.

I tried to put all the objects in an array before I used them with `objects = cursor.to_a`, but the the call blocks any further calculations while it waits for the data to download and is ultimately slower.

Another way I thought of is to append the documents in an array as I'm doing the calculations, then use the array to do further calculations. Though this is pretty unclean and hard to maintain.

Is there any code out there that already does this?

Comment: If you say that your second solution is hard to maintain because you don't have a first "calculation" loop, have you thought about caching the the objects? This way in every loop you would check if there are already objects in cache, and if so use them. If you have a always first loop you can add objects to the array each time you do one calculation as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's already a method that does this in Mongoid. It caches per-query and per iteration, so it really only keeps the data in memory when you query for it, so it doesn't block.

It's just a function on the cursor and you can call it like this:

`Model.where(:name => "John").cache`

[More info here: http://mongoid.org/docs/extras.html](http://mongoid.org/docs/extras.html)

Comment: Do you know if this cache expires at the end of the request?  Docs don't seem to say.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `identity_map`, more details you can find in the doc: http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html

> identity_map_enabled (false): When set to true Mongoid will store
>   documents loaded from the database in the identity map by their ids,
>   so subsequent dataabase queries for the same document in the same unit
>   of work do not hit the database. This is only for relation queries at
>   the moment. See the identity map documentation for more info.

Comment: The identity map would not help since I'm iterating over every object of the cursor and not selecting specific objects by ids.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: Store only the `id` part in the array. `Mongo::Cursor` is not a hash in itself but something similar to a pointer of the result set as far as I can understand. More on that here: [Mongo Docs](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.1.5/file.FAQ.html#Why_can_t_I_access_random_elements_within_a_cursor_)